# Why are the power pins on an L298 H-Bridge named "Vss" & "Vs"

Tags: h-bridge, pins, l298

I understand that Vs is where the H-Bridge gets it's power for driving the motors and that Vss is used for driving the logic, and they both sink to a common ground named "GND". My question is why are they named "Vss" and "Vs" instead of "Vdd" and "Vd" like in any other chip where Vdd is the positive voltage input. Thanks

Comment: Historical reasons of FET vs. BJT

Comment: ^The above comment is incorrect. If he was asking why it was called "Vdd instead of Vcc" then you would be correct (d = drain, c = collector). The pinout actually seems to go against all pin naming conventions I have seen before. I understand Vs is Vsupply, but Vss is the standard for Vsource (which is generally connected to the source of a MOSFET, and in N-channel devices to GND). In my opinion "Vss" should not be called "Vss", but "Vdd" instead. "Vss" should be the negative side of the power supply (0V).

Comment: Oh, OK, nice no see i'm not the only one who found it weird. Thanks